# Reload after upload files in html

Tags: html, forms, file-upload, onbeforeunload

I have an html form, which can be used to upload files. These files are deleted when the user navigates away into another section. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing what can be done if the user decides to reload the page or close the browser window.

I was trying to use both jQuery's `$('window').on('beforeunload')` but all I can achieve is a confirmation message.

Does anybody have a better idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will be pretty hard as it will be browser specific, IE doesnt support many of the events. for the reload you could add a parameter to the form action like ?refresh=true then check for that. if they close the window you dont have many options. Sorry I can be more help